Firefox does not activate when opening urls from the command line
I'm running Firefox 130.0.1 on Fedora 40. When opening URLs from the command line (e.g., by typing firefox google.com), the URL opens successfully, but Firefox doesn't activate -- that is, it does not come to the foreground (and when on another desktop, it does not cause the desktop to switch to the correct one).
Even opening the url in a new window (firefox --new-window google.com) causes the new window to open behind the existing window.
Is there any way to change this behavior?

See https://askubuntu.com/questions/675011/how-do-i-make-firefox-open-in-the-foreground-when-clicking-a-link-in-thunderbird for similar question

I agree it's a similar question, but it's almost a decade old and without answers. I think the behavior I'm seeing is a Firefox issue because other applications (Chrome, Gimp, etc) appear to behave differently.

It might be a bug in the Linux version of Firefox, since it does come to the fore in Windows when called from command line. Is this the Snap Firefox version, or the latest stable package from Mozilla as PPA [https://launchpad.net/~mozillateam/+archive/ubuntu/ppa]?

This is Firefox installed from the Fedora rpm (which appears to be tracking very closely the upstream release, since the package provides 130.0.1).
